# What is the equivalent of MATLAB's imfill(BW,locations,conn) in OpenCV , C++?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I think I should use `floodFill`, but I don't know how exactly.
Note that the problem is with this specific variation of `imfill`, with these parameters.

Comment: If you correctly choose the opencv parameters you can get the same results as you get with matlab. Because the formula behind both opencv and matlab is same. You may check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5N9rYdKUN4E) also, it may help about usage.

Comment: "with these parameters" Which ones?

Comment: By adding what kind of inputs you have, and desired outputs, we may help about the paramter usage.

Comment: @CrisLuengo 
BW, locations, conn
as opoosed to only an image for example, as shown in the doc - 
https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html#d123e141719

Answer (score 2):

**MATLAB**

According to [MATLAB's documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html#:%7E:text=BW2%20%3D%20imfill(%20BW%20%2C%20locations%20%2C%20conn%20)%20fills%20the,where%20conn%20specifies%20the%20connectivity.&text=BW2%20%3D%20imfill(%20BW%20%2C%27holes%27)%20fills%20holes%20in,the%20edge%20of%20the%20image.):

- `BW` is the binary image (black & white image)
- `locations` are pixel coordinates where the operation has to be initiated
- `conn` the type of connectivity; how the neighboring pixels need to be filled. [more details here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html#buo3g4l-1-conn)

**OpenCV**

OpenCV's `floodfill()` has those parameters and a few more. [Check this page for details](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga366aae45a6c1289b341d140839f18717)

There are 4 parameters that are must be passed:

- `image`: this can be 1 or 3-channel image (similar to `BW` in MATLAB)
- `mask`: 1-channel image that must be 2 pixels larger in height and width than `image`
- `seedPoint`: the point where the flood fill operation must start (similar to `locations` in MATLAB)
- `newVal`: the new pixel value to be assigned to locations including and surrounding the `seedPoint`.

The optional parameter `flags` allows you to choose the connectivity (similar to `conn` in MATLAB). The good thing about `flags` is that you can come up with combinations. A few examples:

- `flags = 4`   -> flood operation with 4-way connectivity
- `flags = 8`   -> flood operation with 8-way connectivity
- `flags = 4 | (255 << 8)` -> flood operation with 4-way connectivity and fill the  mask with value 255

There are additional options that can be used [see here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gab87810a476a9cb660435a4cd7871c9eb)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! tried to upvote but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find a solution, the general form of it is as follows:
for an image `Mat im`, and vector of locations `vector<Point> vec` and using the default of connectivity = 4:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    floodFill(im, vec[i], Scalar(255, 255, 255));
}
```